# How to create a % difference arrow line with value in a bar chart using D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to create a bar chart with have one additional functionality to display the % difference from consecutive bar values. To understand the requirement better please have a look into the below image:

[image]

You can see the highlighted arrows which is displaying the %increase value. for example:
(6453-5388)/5388 = ~20%

How to achieve this? I am trying to create this using D3.js

I am going to have a data like below:

```
var barData = [{
    "Year": "2019",
    "Value": 5388
},
{
    "Year": "2020",
    "Value": 6453
},
{
    "Year": "2021",
    "Value": 7345
}];
```

Please help me with your valuable suggestions and solution to achieve this.

Comment: Please show us the code you have so far and describe what you have tried. This link should help you create an example: [link]https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @AHaworth I have not started created the visualization yet. I am looking for some help to understand where to start and creating bars is fine and I can do that by following the D3.js website but the difference % line and value to display is the challenging area for me to think on. If you can help me to understand where to start, that will be helpful.

Comment: Please put up the code you have that creates the bar chart and make sure it is a runnable snippet (i.e. that any library you are using is also loaded) so we can see where things are so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a snippet based on your data and sketch. The sizes / offsets / positions are very proprietary, please adjust them according to your design requirements.

```js
var barData = [{
    "Year": "2019",
    "Value": 5388
},
{
    "Year": "2020",
    "Value": 6453
},
{
    "Year": "2021",
    "Value": 7345
}];

const svg = d3.select('svg');

const xScale = d3.scaleBand()
    .domain(barData.map(d => d.Year))
    .range([0, 240]);
       
    
const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);
  
  svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(50,170)')
    .call(xAxis);

const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 10000])
    .range([150, 0]);
    
const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale).ticks(4);
  
  svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', `translate(50,20)`)
    .call(yAxis);

const bars = svg.selectAll('g.bar')
  .data(barData)
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .classed('bar', true)
  .attr('transform', d => `translate(${xScale(d.Year) + 50 + xScale.bandwidth() / 2}, 170)`)
  
  bars.append('rect')
    .attr('x', -20)
    .attr('width', 40)
    .attr('y', d => -150 + yScale(d.Value))
    .attr('height', d => 150 - yScale(d.Value))
    .style('fill', 'blue')
    
 bars.append('text')
    .text(d => d.Value)
  .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
  .attr('y', d => -155 + yScale(d.Value))
  
bars.filter((d, i) => i < barData.length - 1)
  .append('path')
  .attr('d', (d, i) => `M 5,${-170 + yScale(d.Value)} V ${-210 + yScale(d.Value)} H ${xScale.bandwidth() - 5} V ${-180 + yScale(barData[i + 1].Value)}`)
  .style('stroke', 'gray')
  .style('fill', 'none')
  .attr('marker-end', 'url(#arrowhead)')
  
bars.filter((d, i) => i < barData.length - 1)
  .append('rect')
  .attr('x', 15)
  .attr('y', d => -220 + yScale(d.Value))
  .attr('width', xScale.bandwidth() - 30)
  .attr('height', 20)
  .attr('rx', 10)
  .style('fill', 'white')
  .style('stroke', 'gray');
  
bars.filter((d, i) => i < barData.length - 1)
  .append('text')
  .text((d, i) => `${barData[i + 1].Value > d.Value ? '+' : '-'}${Math.round((barData[i + 1].Value / d.Value * 100) - 100)}%`)
  .attr('x', xScale.bandwidth() / 2)
  .attr('y', d => -207 + yScale(d.Value))
  .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
  .style('fill', 'black');
```

```css
text {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: "Ubuntu";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="300" height="200">
  <defs>
    <marker id="arrowhead" markerWidth="10" markerHeight="7" 
    refX="0" refY="3.5" orient="auto">
      <polygon fill="gray" points="0 0, 10 3.5, 0 7" />
    </marker>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you Michael Rovinsky, I will try this out and will let you know. But thank you so much for your kind help.

Comment: Hi @michael , Thanks for your kind help. I was trying to make the code little dynamic but I am struggling on this. Could you please have a look at the JSFiddle, I have pasted my tried code. Your help really means a lot.
https://jsfiddle.net/AmitSah/g6btjra3/#&togetherjs=hM7VJixrpI

Comment: @AmitkumarSah can you please post another question with explanation of the problem and snippet code and I will try to solve

Comment: Sure @Michael :)

Comment: HI Michael, I have created an another thread and below is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67638126/trying-to-make-dynamic-d3-chart-with-bar-and-difference-line-value-this-is-cont