# Trying to make dynamic D3 Chart with Bar and Difference line/value

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I have asked the below help with respect to creation of Bar chart with showing difference value percentage and line, below is the link:

[How to create a % difference arrow line with value in a bar chart using D3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67605637/how-to-create-a-difference-arrow-line-with-value-in-a-bar-chart-using-d3-js)

I have created this thread to seek help on making the same chart more dynamic and below are my try:

1. Making it dynamic in a way to fit in any resolution i.e making responsive (any width and height of Div can render the chart)
2. Tryin to do a reverse difference calculation.(currently it is calculating forward difference calculation and showing forward arrow, but with backward calculation need to show arrow in backward direction)

(**Edited**:
For example: the calculation is basically will start from last bar and then it will continue till the first bar. for example: (6453-7345)/7345 = -12% and (6453-5388)/6453 = -17%.)

[image]

3. Trying to get the difference by first bar and last bar value i.e:
   [image]

Also below is the code:

```js
var barData = [{
    "Time": "2019",
    "Value": 5388
    },
    {
    "Time": "2020",
    "Value": 6453
    },
    {
    "Time": "2021",
    "Value": 4345
    },
    {
    "Time": "2022",
    "Value": 7345
    },
    {
    "Time": "2023",
    "Value": 5345
    }];

    // Consider this width and Height are dynamic for div "graphID" because I am trying to responsive design
    const divWidth = 700,
    divHeight = 700;
    //Adding Margin to Viz Area
    var margin = {top: 30, right: 50, bottom: 0, left: 50},
    width = parseInt(divWidth,10) - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = parseInt(divHeight,10) - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    
    //To add svg in the visualization node i.e Dome node                    
    const svg = d3.select("#graphID").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
    
    //Adding x axis width i.e based on Viz Width                    
    const xScale = d3.scaleBand()
    .domain(barData.map(d => d.Time))
    .range([0, width]);


    const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);
    
    //Adding g attribute to svg for x axis
    svg.append('g')
    //.attr('transform', 'translate(20,170)')
    .attr("transform", "translate(10," + (height - 50) + ")") 
    .call(xAxis);
    
                        
    /*
    //To get the Max value from an json object
    const maxVal = barData.reduce((acc, shot) => acc = acc > shot.Value ? acc : shot.Value, 0);
    const valMax = Math.max.apply(barData, barData.map(function(o) { return o.Value; }));
    alert(valMax);
    
    const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, maxVal+(maxVal/2)])
    .range([150, 0]);
    */
    
    const yAxisMax = Math.max.apply(barData, barData.map(function(o) { return o.Value; }));
    
    const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, yAxisMax+(yAxisMax/2)])
    .range([height, 0]);

    const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale).ticks(4);
    
    svg.append('g')
    //.attr('transform', 'translate(50,170)')
    .attr("transform", "translate(10,-50)") 
    //.attr("transform", "translate(20," + (height - 50) + ")") 
    .call(yAxis);

    const bars = svg.selectAll('g.bar')
    .data(barData)
    .enter()
    .append('g')
    .classed('bar', true)
    .attr('transform', d => `translate(${xScale(d.Time) + 50 + xScale.bandwidth() / 20}, 170)`)

    bars.append('rect')
    .attr('x', -10)
    .attr('width', 40)
    .attr('y', d =>  -height + yScale(d.Value))
    .attr('height', d => yScale(d.Value) )
    .style('fill', 'blue')

    bars.append('text')
    .text(d => d.Value)
    .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
    .attr('y', d => -(height - 55) + yScale(d.Value))

    bars.filter((d, i) => i < barData.length - 1)
    .append('path')
    .attr('d', (d, i) => `M 5,${-170 + yScale(d.Value)} V ${-210 + yScale(d.Value)} H ${xScale.bandwidth() - 5} V ${-180 + yScale(barData[i + 1].Value)}`)
    .style('stroke', 'gray')
    .style('fill', 'none')
    .attr('marker-end', 'url(#arrowhead)')

    bars.filter((d, i) => i < barData.length - 1)
    .append('rect')
    .attr('x', 15)
    .attr('y', d => -220 + yScale(d.Value))
    .attr('width', xScale.bandwidth() - 30)
    .attr('height', 20)
    .attr('rx', 10)
    .style('fill', 'white')
    .style('stroke', 'gray');

    bars.filter((d, i) => i < barData.length - 1)
    .append('text')
    .text((d, i) => `${barData[i + 1].Value > d.Value ? '+' : '-'}${Math.round((barData[i + 1].Value / d.Value * 100) - 100)}%`)
    .attr('x', xScale.bandwidth() / 2)
    .attr('y', d => -207 + yScale(d.Value))
    .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
    .style('fill', 'black');
```

```css
#graphID
{
    width:500px;
    height:700px
}
text {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: "Ubuntu";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="graphID" width=500 height=700>

</div>
```

Comment: I can undertand the need to be responsive on size (1) and the difference between the first and the last(3). What I don't understand is issue 2 (reverse difference calculation). How do you define which pair of values should show the reverse difference?

Comment: Okay , for issue 2 the calculation is basically will start from last bar and then it will continue till the first bar. for example: (6453-7345)/7345 = -12% and (6453-5388)/6453 = -17%. I will edit the post and also add this same in there. I hope this is clear now. if not then please let me know. :)

Comment: I understand how to calculate, I don't understand how to show the change in both directions... I also think it's a lot of coding to do all the issues at once. I suggest to split the question into two steps (one for responsiveness and second for the difference calculation) otherwise it will be hard to manage...

Comment: Yeah understand, that's why I am trying to make it responsive at first. I have shared the first issue related code only. The other issues will be taken at later. Could you please help me with the responsive implementation. I am trying but struggling. Your help will be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution for responsive sizing:

1. Get dimentions of your parent container:

```js
  const container = d3.select('#graph');
  const divWidth = parseInt(container.style('width'));
  const divHeight = parseInt(container.style('height'));
```

2. Create SVG with the DIV dimentions:

```js
const svg = container.append("svg")
 .attr("width", divWidth)
 .attr("height", divHeight);
```

3. Calculate the chart size using the margins:

```js
const margin = {top: 30, right: 50, bottom: 50, left: 50};
const width = divWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
const height = divHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;
```

4. Add a parent `<g>` and position it using the margins. All other elements should be placed under:

```js
const svgG = svg.append("g")
   .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);
```

```js
    var barData = [{
        "Time": "2019",
        "Value": 5388
        },
        {
        "Time": "2020",
        "Value": 6453
        },
        {
        "Time": "2021",
        "Value": 4345
        },
        {
        "Time": "2022",
        "Value": 7345
        },
        {
        "Time": "2023",
        "Value": 5345
        }];

    const container = d3.select('#graph');
  const divWidth = parseInt(container.style('width'));
    const divHeight = parseInt(container.style('height'));

// Consider this width and Height are dynamic for div "graphID" because I am trying to responsive design
    const margin = {top: 30, right: 50, bottom: 50, left: 50};
  const width = divWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
  const height = divHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;
        
        //To add svg in the visualization node i.e Dome node                    
 const svg = container.append("svg")
   .attr("width", divWidth)
   .attr("height", divHeight);
      
 const svgG = svg.append("g")
   .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);
        
const xScale = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(barData.map(d => d.Time))
  .range([0, width]);

const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);
        
//Adding g attribute to svg for x axis
svgG.append('g')
    .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height})`) 
    .call(xAxis);
        
const yAxisMax = barData.reduce((max, item) => Math.max(max, item.Value), 0) * 1.5;
        
const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, yAxisMax])
    .range([height, 0]);

const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale).ticks(4);
        
svgG.append('g')
    .call(yAxis);

const bars = svgG.selectAll('g.bar')
    .data(barData)
    .enter()
    .append('g')
  .classed('bar', true)
  .attr('transform', d => `translate(${xScale(d.Time) + xScale.bandwidth() / 2}, 0)`)

bars.append('rect')
    .attr('x', -20)
    .attr('width', 40)
    .attr('y', d =>  yScale(d.Value))
    .attr('height', d => height - yScale(d.Value) )
    .style('fill', 'blue')

bars.append('text')
    .text(d => d.Value)
    .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
    .attr('y', d => yScale(d.Value))
  .attr('dy', -5)

bars.filter((d, i) => i < barData.length - 1)
    .append('path')
    .attr('d', (d, i) => `M 5,${yScale(d.Value) - 20} V ${Math.min(yScale(d.Value), yScale(barData[i + 1].Value)) - 60} H ${xScale.bandwidth() - 5} V ${yScale(barData[i + 1].Value) - 20}`)
        .style('stroke', 'gray')
        .style('fill', 'none')
        .attr('marker-end', 'url(#arrowhead)')

bars.filter((d, i) => i < barData.length - 1)
  .append('rect')
  .attr('x', 15)
  .attr('y', (d, i) => Math.min(yScale(d.Value), yScale(barData[i + 1].Value)) - 70)
  .attr('width', xScale.bandwidth() - 30)
  .attr('height', 20)
  .attr('rx', 10)
  .style('fill', 'white')
  .style('stroke', 'gray');

bars.filter((d, i) => i < barData.length - 1)
    .append('text')
    .text((d, i) => `${barData[i + 1].Value > d.Value ? '+' : '-'}${Math.round((barData[i + 1].Value / d.Value * 100) - 100)}%`)
  .attr('x', xScale.bandwidth() / 2)
  .attr('y', (d, i) => Math.min(yScale(d.Value), yScale(barData[i + 1].Value)) - 56)
  .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
  .style('fill', 'black');
```

```css
#graph
{
  width:500px;
  height:700px
 }
 
 text {
   font-size: 12px;
   font-family: "Ubuntu";
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="graph">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks you Michael, You are awesome.  It really helped me a lot to understand and start with. I will be trying to solve the 2nd and 3rd issue and if I required any help or stuck anywhere then will raise a separate thread for that. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Just wanted to know, is it simple to make the same chart to work in Horizontal? or its a lot's of changes in code?

Comment: It can be relatively easy without differential labels: you just switch Y and X scales / axis and replace `y` and `height` with `x` and `width` for bars. With labels it more difficult, because the path calculation is based on layout...

Comment: Hi Michael, I see, maybe I will check on horizontal property later on but need to help on below --> I was trying with some -ve values in barData array but it is not working as expected because the y axis was default started from "0" but when I set that default by dynamic min value using "const yAxisMin = barData.reduce((min, item) => Math.min(min, item.Value), 0) * 1.5;", then also it is not working as expected. Is there any  other changes required? could you please update your shared code with handing the -ve values. Your help appreciable. :)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. What are -ve values?

Comment: Maybe it's a better idea to post a new question with your current code snippet and explanation of the problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232850/discussion-between-amit-kumar-sah-and-michael-rovinsky).

Comment: Sure, Created new Question Thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67686738/making-chart-render-for-negative-value-efficiently-thread-continuation-of-67