# Making Chart render for negative value efficiently

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This thread is a continuation of below:
[Trying to make dynamic D3 Chart with Bar and Difference line/value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67638126/trying-to-make-dynamic-d3-chart-with-bar-and-difference-line-value-this-is-cont)

I was trying to test the chart using negative values (i.e -ve) but it is not working properly. I made some changes in the yAxis scale Domain by passing dynamic min value instead of static "0" value.

At "0" there should be a dotted line and the -ve value should display down of that and +ve (positive values) values start from "0" and height till its value.

Please help me to solve the issue.

Below is the Code:

```js
var barData = [{
    "Time": "2019",
    "Value": 5388
  },
  {
    "Time": "2020",
    "Value": 6453
  },
  {
    "Time": "2021",
    "Value": -4345
  },
  {
    "Time": "2022",
    "Value": 7345
  },
  {
    "Time": "2023",
    "Value": 8345
  },
  {
    "Time": "2024",
    "Value": 5345
  },
  {
    "Time": "2025",
    "Value": 6345
  },
  {
    "Time": "2026",
    "Value": 3345
  }
];

const container = d3.select('#graph');
const divWidth = parseInt(container.style('width'));
const divHeight = parseInt(container.style('height'));

// Consider this width and Height are dynamic for div "graphID" because I am trying to responsive design
const margin = {
  top: 30,
  right: 50,
  bottom: 50,
  left: 50
};
const width = divWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
const height = divHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;

//To add svg in the visualization node i.e Dome node                    
const svg = container.append("svg")
  .attr("width", divWidth)
  .attr("height", divHeight)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);

//To add tooltip for bar
var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div").attr("class", "toolTip");

const defs = svg.append("defs");

const marker = defs.append("marker")
  .attr("id", "arrowhead")
  .attr("markerWidth", "10")
  .attr("markerHeight", "7")
  .attr("refX", "0")
  .attr("refY", "3.5")
  .attr("orient", "auto")

const polygon = marker.append("polygon")
  .attr("fill", "gray")
  .attr("points", "0 0, 10 3.5, 0 7")

const xScale = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(barData.map(d => d.Time))
  .range([0, width + margin.right]);

const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);

//Adding g attribute to svg for x axis
svg.append('g')
  .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height})`)
  .call(xAxis);

const yAxisMax = barData.reduce((max, item) => Math.max(max, item.Value), 0) * 1.5;

const yAxisMin = barData.reduce((min, item) => Math.min(min, item.Value), 0) * 1.5;

const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([yAxisMin, yAxisMax])
  .range([height, 0]);

const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale).ticks(4);

svg.append('g')
  .call(yAxis);

const bars = svg.selectAll('g.bar')
  .data(barData)
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .classed('bar', true)
  .attr('transform', d => `translate(${xScale(d.Time) + xScale.bandwidth() / 2}, 0)`);
/*  
const staticColor =   "steelblue",
highlightColor = "orange";

var sheet = document.createElement('style')
sheet.innerHTML = ".bar {fill: "+staticColor+"} .highlight {fill:"+highlightColor+"}";
document.body.appendChild(sheet);
*/
bars.append('rect')
  .attr('x', -20)
  .attr('width', 40)
  .attr('y', d => yScale(d.Value))
  .attr('height', d => height - yScale(d.Value))
  .attr('fill', 'blue')
  //.attr("class", "bar")
  .on("mousemove", onMouseOver)
  .on("mouseout", onMouseOut);

function onMouseOver(d, i) {
  tooltip
    .style("left", d3.event.pageX - 50 + "px")
    .style("top", d3.event.pageY - 70 + "px")
    .style("display", "inline-block")
    .html("Year: " + (d.Time) + "<br>" + "Value: " + (d.Value));
  d3.select(this).attr('fill', "#eec42d");
  //d3.select(this).attr('class', 'highlight');
  //this.setState({ fillColour: 'green' });


}

function onMouseOut(d, i) {
  tooltip.style("display", "none");
  d3.select(this).attr('fill', "blue");
  //d3.select(this).attr('class', 'bar');
  //this.setState({ fillColour: 'blue' });
}

bars.append('text')
  .text(d => d.Value)
  .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
  .attr('y', d => yScale(d.Value))
  .attr('dy', -5);

bars.filter((d, i) => i < barData.length - 1)
  .append('path')
  .attr('d', (d, i) => `M 5,${yScale(d.Value) - 20} V ${Math.min(yScale(d.Value), yScale(barData[i + 1].Value)) - 60} H ${xScale.bandwidth() - 5} V ${yScale(barData[i + 1].Value) - 25}`)
  .style('stroke', 'gray')
  .style('fill', 'none')
  .attr('marker-end', 'url(#arrowhead)')

bars.filter((d, i) => i < barData.length - 1)
  .append('rect')
  .attr('x', 15)
  .attr('y', (d, i) => Math.min(yScale(d.Value), yScale(barData[i + 1].Value)) - 70)
  .attr('width', xScale.bandwidth() - 30)
  .attr('height', 20)
  .attr('rx', 10)
  .style('fill', 'white')
  .style('stroke', 'gray');

bars.filter((d, i) => i < barData.length - 1)
  .append('text')
  .text((d, i) => `${barData[i + 1].Value > d.Value ? '+' : ''}${Math.round((barData[i + 1].Value / d.Value * 100) - 100)}%`)
  .attr('x', xScale.bandwidth() / 2)
  .attr('y', (d, i) => Math.min(yScale(d.Value), yScale(barData[i + 1].Value)) - 56)
  .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
  .style('fill', 'black');
```

```css
#graph {
  width: 600px;
  height: 500px;
}

text {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: "Ubuntu";
}

.toolTip {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  min-width: 80px;
  height: auto;
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #6F257F;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="graph">
</div>
```

Comment: If you want to make it horizontal, the zero point should be right in the middle of the X axis?

Comment: I am not making the chart horizontal, Only trying to make the chart to work properly with negative values (-ve) . when there is a -ve value in barData array then the +ve value bar should start from "0" in upward and -ve value bar downward direction. Also if we can add a dotted line on "0" scale that will make a good eye catchup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const barData = [{
"Time": "2019",
"Value": 5388
  },
  {
"Time": "2020",
"Value": 6453
  },
  {
"Time": "2021",
"Value": -4345
  },
  {
"Time": "2022",
"Value": 7345
  },
  {
"Time": "2023",
"Value": 8345
  },
  {
"Time": "2024",
"Value": 5345
  },
  {
"Time": "2025",
"Value": 6345
  },
  {
"Time": "2026",
"Value": 3345
  }
];

const container = d3.select('#graph');
const divWidth = parseInt(container.style('width'));
const divHeight = parseInt(container.style('height'));

// Consider this width and Height are dynamic for div "graphID" because I am trying to responsive design
const margin = {
  top: 50,
  right: 50,
  bottom: 50,
  left: 50
};
const width = divWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
const height = divHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;

//To add svg in the visualization node i.e Dome node                    
const svg = container.append("svg")
  .attr("width", divWidth)
  .attr("height", divHeight)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);

//To add tooltip for bar
const tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div").attr("class", "toolTip");

const defs = svg.append("defs");

const marker = defs.append("marker")
  .attr("id", "arrowhead")
  .attr("markerWidth", "10")
  .attr("markerHeight", "7")
  .attr("refX", "0")
  .attr("refY", "3.5")
  .attr("orient", "auto")

const polygon = marker.append("polygon")
  .attr("fill", "gray")
  .attr("points", "0 0, 10 3.5, 0 7")

const xScale = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(barData.map(d => d.Time))
  .range([0, width + margin.right]);

const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale)

//Adding g attribute to svg for x axis
const yAxisMax = barData.reduce((max, item) => Math.max(max, item.Value), 0) * 1.5;

const yAxisMin = barData.reduce((min, item) => Math.min(min, item.Value), 0) * 1.5;

const yAxisRange = Math.max(yAxisMax, Math.abs(yAxisMin));

const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([-yAxisRange, yAxisRange])
  .range([height, 0]);

const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale).ticks(4);

svg.append('g')
  .call(yAxis);

const bars = svg.selectAll('g.bar')
  .data(barData)
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .classed('bar', true)
  .attr('transform', d => `translate(${xScale(d.Time) + xScale.bandwidth() / 2}, 0)`);

bars.append('rect')
  .attr('x', -20)
  .attr('width', 40)
  .attr('y', d => Math.min(yScale(d.Value), height/2))
  .attr('height', d => d.Value > 0 ?
(height/2 - yScale(d.Value)) : 
(yScale(d.Value) - height/2)
  )
  .attr('fill', 'blue')
  .on("mousemove", onMouseOver)
  .on("mouseout", onMouseOut);

function onMouseOver(d, i) {
  tooltip
.style("left", d3.event.pageX - 50 + "px")
.style("top", d3.event.pageY - 70 + "px")
.style("display", "inline-block")
.html("Year: " + (d.Time) + "<br>" + "Value: " + (d.Value));
  d3.select(this).attr('fill', "#eec42d");
}

function onMouseOut(d, i) {
  tooltip.style("display", "none");
  d3.select(this).attr('fill', "blue");
}

bars.append('text')
  .text(d => d.Value)
  .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
  .attr('alignment-baseline', d => d.Value > 0 ? 'baseline' : 'hanging')
  .attr('y', d => yScale(d.Value))
  .attr('dy', d => d.Value > 0 ? -5 : 5);

bars.filter((d, i) => i < barData.length - 1)
  .append('path')
  .attr('d', (d, i) => `M 5,${Math.min(yScale(d.Value) - 20, height/2)} V ${Math.min(yScale(d.Value), yScale(barData[i + 1].Value)) - 60} H ${xScale.bandwidth() - 5} V ${Math.min(yScale(barData[i + 1].Value) - 25, height/2 - 10)}`)
  .style('stroke', 'gray')
  .style('fill', 'none')
  .attr('marker-end', 'url(#arrowhead)')

bars.filter((d, i) => i < barData.length - 1)
  .append('rect')
  .attr('x', 15)
  .attr('y', (d, i) => Math.min(yScale(d.Value), yScale(barData[i + 1].Value)) - 70)
  .attr('width', xScale.bandwidth() - 30)
  .attr('height', 20)
  .attr('rx', 10)
  .style('fill', 'white')
  .style('stroke', 'gray');

bars.filter((d, i) => i < barData.length - 1)
  .append('text')
  .text((d, i) => `${barData[i + 1].Value > d.Value ? '+' : ''}${Math.round((barData[i + 1].Value / d.Value * 100) - 100)}%`)
  .attr('x', xScale.bandwidth() / 2)
  .attr('y', (d, i) => Math.min(yScale(d.Value), yScale(barData[i + 1].Value)) - 56)
  .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
  .style('fill', 'black');

const xAxisG = svg.append('g')
  .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height/2})`)
  .call(xAxis);
  
xAxisG.selectAll('.tick').each(function() {
  const tick = d3.select(this);
  const text = tick.select('text').text();
  const data = barData.find(d => d.Time === text);
  if (data.Value < 0) {
tick.select('text').style('fill', 'white');
tick.select('line').style('stroke', 'white');
  }
})
```

```css
#graph {
  width: 700px;
  height: 500px;
}

text {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: "Ubuntu";
}

.toolTip {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  min-width: 80px;
  height: auto;
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #6F257F;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="graph">
</div>
```

Comment: It's working fine if data is having -ve value but when data is not having -ve value then also the -ve Yaxis is showing. Is that not possible to handle?  Basically if value contain -ve then the solution which you gave should show chart in that way and if data not containing any -ve value then no -ve Yaxis should show. Is that possible to do?

Comment: A graph with both positive and negative values should have different layout than a graph with positive values only. So you can first check your data and then decide if you use the old layout or the new one... But I don't think you can apply same layout for both cases

Comment: Sure, if that is the only way then that should be fine. But it helped me a lot. Thank you once again.

Comment: Is it possible to not to have same max  -ve value for YAxis i.e  the +ve and -ve  YAxis are syncronised because you took max from min and max value from data. and plot the Y Axis accordingly. Can't we have -ve YAxis based on max of -ve values from the data?

Comment: Yes it's possible, but then you need to calculate exact position of zero line instead of assuming it's (height / 2)... It just will complicate your code a little

Comment: OKay, maybe I will try to do that and if I face any issue then will create a new thread for this. Thanks Michael.

Comment: Hi Michael, I am facing one issue i.e when trying to reverse the marker direction, it is not working. I an trying to make the marker at start but arrow is not coming fine. I think the polygon is not working as expected for marker-start (i.e .attr('marker-start', 'url(#arrowhead)') )

Comment: I have created a different thread for the above issue, your help is highly appreciable. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67997760/backward-direction-of-path-with-arrow-is-not-showing-properly-in-d3-js-v5

Comment: Hi Michael, is there any way we can add some transition to bars? I was trying but it is not working. Any help on this is highly appreciable.